# Move Linked issues from one user story to another

Tags: jira

I have a JIRA user story with multiple Linked issues, some open, and some closed. I need to move all Linked issues in open status to another user story. How can I do this in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for issues using function called: [linkedIssues(issueKey)](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-service-management-cloud/docs/advanced-search-reference-jql-functions/#Advancedsearchingfunctionsreference-linkedIssueslinkedIssues--)
From JQL filter view you can bulk update issues:
[image: Bulk change issues in JQL search view]

Comment: I have tried that, and bulk update does not have an option for us to change/update linked issues.

Comment: @abhijit.bhatta I thought you want to update parent link. 
To update linked-issue maybe this can help: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1229492/issue-link-manager-for-jira?tab=overview&hosting=cloud

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to go to the Parent issue, and go down to the section where the sub-tasks are listed. Click the '...' and select 'hide done' to hide the completed items.

From the dropdown select 'Bulk edit'.

Choose the issues to be moved.

On the next screen choose Move. You are moving the Issues to a new parent. You will then see the options you need to select the new Parent either in the current Project or another.